# Vuex not change isLogin variable to false ()

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Why this function `context.commit('changeIsLogin', false);` not working after

```
logout() {
  localStorage.removeItem('token');
  this.$store.dispatch('asyncValidateToken'); 
}
```

in this code? isLogin not change to false:

```
export default function (/* { ssrContext } */) {
    const Store = new Vuex.Store({
        state: {
            isLogin: false
        },
        mutations: {
            changeIsLogin (state, payload) {
                state.isLogin += payload
            }
        },
        actions: {
            asyncValidateToken: async (context, payload) => {
                await api.post('/accounts/token', '', {
                  headers: {
                        'Authorization': `Bearer ${localStorage.token}`,
                    }
                })
                .then(response => {
                    context.commit('changeIsLogin', true);
                    console.log(response.data);
                    return true
                }, response => {
                    context.commit('changeIsLogin', false);
                    console.error(response.data);
                    return false;
                });
            }
        }
    })
```

Comment: maybe something wrong  of your api function, why it hast two response function?

Comment: I think this `state.isLogin += payload` should be `state.isLogin = payload`.

Comment: Because this function need run "context.commit('changeIsLogin', false);" after "localStorage.removeItem('token');". After this response get error "401 (Unauthorized)". Two response function equivalent this code, but it not work too:               .then(response => {
                    context.commit('changeIsLogin', true);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    context.commit('changeIsLogin', false);
                });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mutation `changeIsLogin` is basically adding the payload to the current state.
So your code:

```
changeIsLogin (state, payload) {
    state.isLogin += payload
}
```

Is basically equivalent to:

```
changeIsLogin (state, payload) {
    state.isLogin = state.isLogin + payload
}
```

Since boolean values can act like number when doing arithmetic operations on them, you'll have the following issues:

```
state.isLogin = false
payload = true
--> 
state.isLogin = true + false = 1

state.isLogin = 1
payload = false
--> 
state.isLogin = 1 + false = 1
```

and so on.

So all you have to do is remove the arithmetic operation:

```
changeIsLogin (state, payload) {
    state.isLogin = payload
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's right! I got lost in three pines. Thank you very much!

Comment: We all do from time to time. :-) You're welcome.